# Using C popen(): read() work, but fread() doesn't

Tags: c, popen, fread

After popen(), fread() always returns 0. Using read() with fileno(fp) works. What's going on?

Here is the code.

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    FILE *fp = popen("echo hello", "r");
    if (!fp) {
        perror("echo hello");
    } else {
        char buffer[128];
        for (;;) {
            int n;
            if (argc < 2) {
                n = fread(buffer, sizeof buffer, 1, fp);
            } else {
                n = read(fileno(fp), buffer, sizeof buffer);
            }
            printf("read %d bytes\n", n);
            if (n <= 0) break;
            fwrite(buffer, n, 1, stdout);
        }
        pclose(fp);
    }
}
```

The code uses fread() if there is no command line argument, read() otherwise.

Output:

```
$ ./test
read 0 bytes
$ ./test x
read 6 bytes
hello
read 0 bytes
```

Comment: `fread()` is failing because it reached EOF before it could read the 100 bytes you told it to read.

Comment: Try: `n = fread(buffer, 1, sizeof buffer, fp);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You told `fread()` to read 1 item 100 bytes long. `fread()` returns the number of complete items that were read. Since the stream only has 6 bytes in it, it can't read any items before reaching EOF, so it returns `0`.

Swap the order of the `size` and `nitem` arguments, then it will treat each byte as a separate item, and return the number of bytes that it read.

```
n = fread(buffer, 1, sizeof buffer, fp);
```

Comment: I am writing my comment now.

Comment: fread() returns the number of items read which, in this case, are bytes. This way it returns the number of bytes. If reversed, as you suggest, it will always return 0. Of course, you can try it and see that you get 0 in either case.